# Unable to get incoming connections on wifi. Outward is ok, cable in/out is ok

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a wifi dongle that works perfectly in other computers, and i can use it with the raspberry just fine except that it seems like it doesn't accept any incoming connections.

I can download stuff, apt-get update and everything, but i can't reach the raspberry from any other computer. No ping, no ssh, nothing. When i run the same commands while on the raspberry, i can both ping and ssh to myself.

At first i thought it was just a firewall issue, but i don't think i have a firewall running on the raspberry. I run a fresh install of Raspbian “wheezy”, fully updated.

Is this anything anyone else has encountered?

Best regards

Comment: Ok, it turned out that it was my crappy Thompson router than caused the problem. Maybe it got confused with 2 IPs both having the name "pi" (wifi and cable connection)? I removed both entries in the router and restarted it, and it magically started working.

Comment: excellent, glad you got it sorted, if you move your comment to an answer for your own question, and in a couple of days you'll be able to accept your own answer, then this can get closed.